# After deploying Istio bookinfo application on EKS, `kubectl get svc` displays the app's services but `Kubectl get pods` returns `no resources found`

Tags: kubernetes, istio, amazon-eks

I installed Istio on my EKS cluster and installed bookinfo from samples.

```
$ sudo Kubectl apply -f /samples/bookinfo/platform/kube/bookinfo.yaml
```

After installation, I am able to see the services but not the pods for those services

```
$ sudo Kubectl get services 

NAME.          TYPE
productpage    ClusterIP.   
ratings.       ClusterIP
reviews.       ClusterIP
```

But the pods in the above services are not to be seen

```
$ sudo Kubectl get pods
No resources found in default namespace
```

Any idea why I can view the services but not the pods in those services installed by booking app?

Comment: What's the istio version you have installed? Could you also verify if by accident you haven't deployed your pods in another namespace with `kubectl get pods -A`?

Comment: all the outputs look to me tampered. `kubectl` with caps, a dot in the end of the services, without passing any namespace...

Answer (score 0):

I've verified the bookinfo app with istio 1.9.3 and it works correctly.

I went to the istio 1.9.3 directory with the following command `cd istio-1.9.3` and used `kubectl apply -f samples/bookinfo/platform/kube/bookinfo.yaml` to install the bookinfo application.

```
kubectl get pods
NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
details-v1-66b6955995-q2nwh       2/2     Running   0          44s
productpage-v1-5d9b4c9849-lhc2b   2/2     Running   0          44s
ratings-v1-fd78f799f-t8gkp        2/2     Running   0          43s
reviews-v1-6549ddccc5-jv2tg       2/2     Running   0          43s
reviews-v2-76c4865449-wjkxx       2/2     Running   0          43s
reviews-v3-6b554c875-9gsnd        2/2     Running   0          42s

kubectl get svc
NAME          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
details       ClusterIP   10.112.2.127   <none>        9080/TCP   81s
kubernetes    ClusterIP   10.112.0.1     <none>        443/TCP    6m41s
productpage   ClusterIP   10.112.5.110   <none>        9080/TCP   75s
ratings       ClusterIP   10.112.1.157   <none>        9080/TCP   79s
reviews       ClusterIP   10.112.1.106   <none>        9080/TCP   78s
```

As you can see both pods and services were deployed correctly.

---

I would just recommend to redeploy the bookinfo application with the newest version and it should work.

Also you can use the [raw.githubusercontent.com](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.9/samples/bookinfo/platform/kube/bookinfo.yaml) instead of the samples directory to deploy it. You can find more about that on istio [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/examples/bookinfo/#start-the-application-services).